# fading slideshow in an imageview. xCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, xcode4.2, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to make a slideshow in an imageview that uses also fade-in fade-out effects.

so far ive done this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo2.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo3.jpg"], nil];

    animationView.animationDuration = 5;
    animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animationView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:animationView];
}
```

images do appear one after the other, in a 5 sec delay, what i want now is to make them fade-in and fade-out each time an image appears, any suggestions on that?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: no one knows the answer tho this? ive been trying for days to find a solution, the only thing i came up (which is not good but kinda works) is by making some voids and calling them with a selector i managed to make images appear like fading in and disappear like fading out (by changing the alpha), but that doesnt work that well, it gives u tho a fake feeling of fading

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to do something similar. What I did was setup a timer that called a `UIView` `transitionWithView` on a `UIImageView` that was incrementing through the array of my slideshow photos.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.welcomePhotos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"welcome_1.png",@"welcome_2.png", @"welcome_3.png", nil];
self.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.welcomePhotos objectAtIndex:0]];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(transitionPhotos) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void)transitionPhotos{

if (photoCount < [self.welcomePhotos count] - 1){
    photoCount ++;
}else{
    photoCount = 0;
}
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView1
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ self.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.welcomePhotos objectAtIndex:photoCount]]; }
                completion:NULL];    
}
```

Comment: How do I declare the `photoCount` in the `.h`?

Comment: photoCount can be declared under the @implementation as static int photoCount;